# Selenium alternative for production application

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I am building a web app that automates navigation (move mouse, click, fill login forme, etc.) on multiple sites. I did a local test with Selenium that works greats.

Now, I am trying to deploy my java spring boot application to Heroku but It seems that Selenium is not meant for this use an I cannot manage to do that.

My question: Is there an other way to achieve the same result but that is easier to use in production?

Comment: Just curious, how does selenium is not meant for this?

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but I cannot manage te deploy selenium on heroku and access it from my webapp.

Comment: @Paul Fournel what steps have you tried so far?